# Definition of dual tensors

Tags: terminology, dual-spaces

It is a clear fact that the dual of vectors is a map taking vectors to real numbers: $V^\ast: \rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$. Following that how to understand intuitively the notion of the dual tensors? Does it take tensors to real numbers?

Comment: What definition of tensors are you using to begin with?

Comment: The first one is the projection of the surface of a parallelogram constructed on vectors $\vec{u}(u^1,u^2,u^3)$, $\vec v(v^1,v^2,v^3)$ on coordinate planes $x_\alpha x_\beta$.

$$df^{\alpha \beta}=du^\alpha dv^\beta-du^{\beta} dv^{\alpha}$$

It is said in a textbook that as an element of integration over the two-dimensional surfaces is taken the dual of $df^{\alpha \beta}$ antisymmetric tensor.

$$ df^{\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\alpha}_{\quad\beta\gamma}df^{\beta\gamma}$$

In that sense how to understand the notion of dual for tensor?

Comment: That doesn't look much like any version of tensors that I'm familiar with, but maybe someone else might be able to make sense of it...

Comment: I would send the screenshot of the paper where it is. In a comment, it is impossible, unfortunately.

Comment: Probably you might know the answer to my previous questions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496231/the-definition-of-the-dual-tensors-ast-qi-frac1p-varepsiloni-j-q-j

Answer (score 1):

It may not be worth it thinking of it that way. Suppose you have an element of $V\otimes V$. This is a tensor. Depending on how you think of tensors, this is an element of a tensor product, a multilinear map from $V^*\times V^* $ to a field, let's stick with $\mathbb{R}$, or a collection of numbers $\{T_{ab}\}$ transforming as a (2,0) covariant object under a change of basis. These different way of thinking about a tensor aren't always equivalent, but for finite dimensional vector spaces and infinite fields they are.

Back to your question: if you understand the dual of $V$, a good way of thinking of the dual of $T\in V\otimes V$ is as an element $T^*$ of $(V \otimes V)^*\simeq V^* \otimes V^*$, which you can identify with a bilinear map from $V \times V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Similarly the dual of an element in $V^*\otimes V^*$ is an element of $(V^*\otimes V^*)^*\simeq V^{**} \otimes V^{**}\simeq V\otimes V$ which you can think of as a bilinear map from $V^*\times V^*$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

What I am trying to say is that by understanding $V^*$, the isomorphism $V^{**} \simeq V$, so that element of $V$ can be identified with linear maps from $V^* $ to $\mathbb{R}$, and the fact that (up to isomorphisms) taking the dual commutes with with taking the tensor product you have a way of understanding the dual of tensor of arbitrary ranks.

A basis $\{e _a\}$ of $V$ canonically determines a basis $\{e^a\}$ of $V^*$ and in turn bases of any tensor product of $V$ and $V^*$, hence by knowing how to take the dual of elements of $V$ and $V^*$, which is simply the map $ e_a \leftrightarrow e^a$ you can take the dual of an arbitrary tensor.

Comment: In a book where the Hodge duality is explained, the idea of duality is described as being between $\Lambda^p$ $p$-forms and $\Lambda_{N-p}$ $N$-$p$-vectors or between $\Lambda^p$ $p$-forms and $\Lambda^{N-p}$ $N-p$-forms. But the idea of dual tensors is not given. How to connect duality between p/vector forms and the duality of tensors?

Comment: That is a different kind of duality, not the one I described, the word "dual" is heavily overused. What you want to look at is the Hodge star operator. The following is just a sketch. The basic idea in 3D would be to associate to a vector the plane orthogonal to it. More precisely, taken an orthonormal basis $\{e _1, e_2, e_3\}$, then $*e_1 = e_2\wedge e_3$. In an $n$ dimensional vector space you do something similar: the star of a wedge product of $k$ vectors of an orthonormal basis is, up to a sign, the wedge product of the remaining basis elements. Extend by linearity.

Comment: Instead of parallelogram projection on $x_1 x_2$ plane is taken its dual vector, perpendicular to $x_1 x_2$ plane and the length is equal to the area of the projection. Is that right?

Comment: Probably you also know the answer to my previous question. <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496862/definition-of-dual-tensors/3497063?noredirect=1#comment7191611_3497063>